# NativeScript/Angular - Reactive form not working

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, angular2-formbuilder, angular-reactive-forms

In component I'm doing this:

```
public loginForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  email: ['', Validators.required],
  password: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

And then in template binding the form:

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical" [formGroup]="loginForm">
  <TextField formControlName="email" hint="Email"></TextField>
  <TextField formControlName="password" hint="Password" secure="true"></TextField>
  <Button text="Log in" (tap)="login()"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

But then when I log the `loginForm` value upon running `login` function it's still empty even if the text fields have values..

I've imported both `ReactiveFormsModule` and the `NativeScriptFormsModule` but doesn't work. If I change `password` to any random name I don't get an error or anything either. So it's like it's not even connected to the form in any way.

What am I doing wrong? I'm on nativescript cli 2.5+ which suggests this code should be working.

**EDIT:**

I've done some digging and it appears that lazy loading modules is what's causing this to break as well as other things. I made a new issue about this here:

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/735

Would be great to hear if anyone else have encountered the same problem and if there is a solution to it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you import the `ReactiveFormsModule` and the `NativeScriptFormsModule` into your actual component's module `imports` (Login.Module.ts), not just the AppModule, because it won't work otherwise!

I did this and then Reactive Forms worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

since you already imported NativeScriptFormsModule, declare a new variable outside FormGroup and try to build your texfield as:

`<TextField hint="Email" [(ngModel)]="yourEmailVariable"></TextField>`

Comment: I would but `FormBuilder` doesn't use ngModel, not does it make sense having to re-declare a bunch of form controls. I've done some digging and it appears that lazy loading is what's causing the issues. I've made a new issue about this here: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/735